# Transform pd.DataFrame() to narrower, longer dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame in which each case contains multiple sets of interesting information. In short, I want the columns to decrease and the data frame to become longer according to pre-specified relationships.

My old data frame looks like this:

```
old = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index', 'residency', 'rating_NYC', 'dist_NYC', 'rating_PAR', 'dist_PAR', 
                            'rating_LON', 'dist_LON', 'rating_MUM', 'dist_MUM', 'gen_rating'],
             data = [[0, 'New York', 9, 2,     5, 8,   4, 9,  3, 8,  6],
                     [1, 'Paris',    5, 9,     7, 1,   6, 2,  4, 6,  7]])
```

Each line is one individual stating her `residency`, rating a city (`rating_xxx`), stating her geographical distance to that city's centre `dist_xxx`, and giving a general rating of living in a city (each range `0`-`10`).

I now want to create a new df with fewer columns and more rows. Each row in the old df yields information for multiple rows in the new one: I want one line per `rating_xxx` / `dist_xxx` combination in the old df (i.e. multiple lines per individual). The new df should contain: the `old_index`, the `rating` of and (iii) `distance` to that particular city, whether the individual is a `resident` of that city and the general rating (`gen_rating`).

For example, the first line in the new df would contain the first individual's ratings of/ distance to NYC and that she is NYC resident (and her general rating); the second line would contain the first individual's rating of/ distance to PAR etc.

Based on the above data frame, the desired output is:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['index', 'old_index', 'rating', 'dist', 'resident', 'gen_rating'],
             data = [      [0,           0,        9,      2,          1,            6], # NYC -> NYC
                           [1,           0,        5,      8,          0,            6], # NYC -> PAR
                           [2,           0,        4,      9,          0,            6], # NYC -> LON
                           [3,           0,        3,      8,          0,            6], # NYR -> MUM
                           [4,           1,        5,      9,          0,            7], # PAR -> NYC
                           [5,           1,        7,      1,          1,            7], # PAR -> PAR
                           [6,           1,        6,      2,          0,            7], # PAR -> LON
                           [7,           1,        4,      6,          0,            7]])# PAR -> MUM
```

Can someone point me to the correct function I need for this and the most efficient way of achieving this? (The actual data frame is a bit larger ;) ) Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first set the columns which remains single for each index as index , then split the column names to create a Multiindex and then use `stack`:

```
old_ = old.set_index(['index','residency','gen_rating'])
old_.columns = old_.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)

(old_.stack().reset_index(['index','gen_rating']).reset_index(drop=True)
                                              .rename_axis('New_Index'))
```

---

```
           index  gen_rating  dist  rating
New_Index                                 
0              0           6     9       4
1              0           6     8       3
2              0           6     2       9
3              0           6     8       5
4              1           7     2       6
5              1           7     6       4
6              1           7     9       5
7              1           7     1       7
```

Or if you want the reference later you can retain the stacked indexes :

```
old_.stack().reset_index(['index','gen_rating'])

               index  gen_rating  dist  rating
residency                                     
New York  LON      0           6     9       4
          MUM      0           6     8       3
          NYC      0           6     2       9
          PAR      0           6     8       5
Paris     LON      1           7     2       6
          MUM      1           7     6       4
          NYC      1           7     9       5
          PAR      1           7     1       7
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! (For later reference: to achieve the desired output, I also used: `old.rename(columns={'index': 'index_old'}, inplace=True)`, `old = old.reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_1': 'rated_city'})`, `old['resident'] = old['residency'] + '-' + old['rated_city']`, and `old['resident'] = old['resident'].map({'New York-NYC': 1, 'Paris-PAR': 1}).fillna(0)` (and reordered with `old = old[['index_old', 'rating', 'dist', 'resident', 'gen_rating']]`)
old.index.name = 'index'